# What would be the Earth acceleration in the units where $\hbar=c=1$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, absolute-units

In my calculations, I have to use the units in which the Planck constant and light velocity must be taken as unity.

Now, what would be the value of Earth's gravitation force $\implies g = G\cdot\frac{M\cdot m}{R^2}$ (G-> Gravitational Constant, M -> Mass of Earth, m -> mass of Other Body, R -> Radius of Earth) in these units?

Comment: You need to convert ms$^{−2}$. Ask yourself what your new length and time units are.

Comment: The convention $\hbar=c=1$ is insufficient to fix the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

One system of units in which $\hbar = 1$ and $c=1$ are [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units).

In Planck units the unit of length is about $1.616 \times 10^{-35}$ metres and the unit of time is about $5.391 \times 10^{-44}$ seconds. From this you can work out what $9.8$ metres per second per second is in Planck units.

Comment: There are multiple unit choices with $\hbar=c=1$.

Comment: @my2cts True. I have amended my answer.